# Make the whole select clickable when using an image absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am creating a select that has its own styling. It has an image that is position absolute and it prevents the whole select to be clickable. Any idea why this is and how to fix that?

**HTML**

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="flex items-center border-b border-jibuttonBlue py relative w-102">
        <select class="w-102 bg-jibackgroundGrey outline-none" name="">
            <option value="">January</option>
            <option value="">February</option>
        </select>
        <img src="{{MEDIA_UI}}/icon-white-bg-default.svg" alt="" class="absolute right-0 select-icon">
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
}
.select-icon {pointer-events: none;}
```

Comment: add HTML & CSS code here

Comment: set `pointer-events: none;` to image?

Comment: HTML code is fine add CSS too

Comment: @AbbasEbadian thanks that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
}

.select-icon {pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <div class="flex items-center border-b border-jibuttonBlue py relative w-102">
            <select class="w-102 bg-jibackgroundGrey outline-none" name="">
              <option value="">January</option>
              <option value="">February</option>
            </select>
            <img src="{{MEDIA_UI}}/icon-white-bg-default.svg" alt="" class="absolute right-0 select-icon">
          </div>
```